# Get property name by id

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

I'm using this code to iterate over the properties passed to a native function:

```
JSObject *iter = JS_NewPropertyIterator(cx, jsargs);
jsid id;
while(JS_NextProperty(cx, iter, &id) && id != JSID_VOID) {
        jsval vp;
        if(!JS_GetPropertyById(cx, jsargs, id, &vp)) {
                continue;
        }
        // ...
}
```

This works fine to get the *value* of the property, however, I need the *name* of that property, too.

I couldn't find any of the various property-related `...ById()` functions which give me the property name.

Comment: @FelixKling: I think the "SpiderMonkey: " in the title was helpful to people seeing this question on the front page. The new title is rather vague without looking at the tags. And according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/147015 tag-like prefixes are often considered good.

Comment: Mmh, sorry. I keep deleting these tag: things. I didn't even notice it was a question from you.... How about '... in SpiderMonkey' ? :) Glad you figured it out though!

Comment: Sigh, i hate people downvoting questions without leaving a comment why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at existing code which needs this behavior (the json encoder) helped.

[`JS_IdToValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_IdToValue) is the function I was looking for.